# Since upgrading to Yosemite, why is the screensaver unresponsive for a few random seconds after it starts?

Tags: macos, screensaver

Since I've upgraded to 10.10 (from 10.8), the screensaver is now unresponsive for some random seconds (~1 to 10) after it starts.

This is very annoying, since I like to have a short "screensaver: start after" time, coupled with a "security: require password after", so that the screensaver starts, but I immediatly hit a button and I can get back to work.

I've already had to increase the "require password after" from "5 seconds" to "1 minute", but this doesn't save me from wasting those unresponsive seconds each time...

Comment: have same issue.  Mid 1012 MBP Retina.  Turned out I had to repair disk with Disk Utility.

Comment: @Joop done. There were a whole lot of permission errors in the printer drivers, and finally an error relative to displaypolicyd. I'll update. Meanwhile you might want to post this as an answer, just in case it works.

Comment: It might be screensaver's fault: I was using "Word of the day", it hasn't happened since I've switched to "Classic". I'm waiting a bit more before posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It likely was screensaver's fault: I was using "Word of the day", it hasn't happened any more since I've switched to "Classic".

Answer (score 0):

Feels to me to be to simple for a full answer, but I had similar problems.   The delays and other issues were solved by doing a Repair Disk and Repair permissions.   I had to do it from recovery partition as I have file vault enabled.   Must admit that it still feels a bit sluggish compared to Mavericks though, but not unbearably so.   Hopefully this will be addressed in point releases.

Comment: It looked like it was working at first, but then… it didn't. Thanks for the try :/

Comment: @Lohoris Yes agree, mine is still slow from time to time.   Have similar "lag" issues elsewhere as well.  E.g. when editing a contact there is an almost ridiculous delay, it is probably new OS issues that will be ironed out in point releases.